# What is the net force experienced (at the lowest point) by a wire being rotated in a vertical circle with a mass 'm' at its free end?

Tags: elasticity, stress-strain, centripetal-force

A metallic wire is being rotated in a vertical circle with a mass $m$ fastened to its end. 
My understanding says that the net force experienced by this mass should be the centripetal force:

$T - mg = mrw^2$

Should not this centripetal force be the net force that is experienced by the wire when the mass is at its lowest position (Action-Reaction pair), and hence only this centripetal force should be responsible for the wire's elongation?

The book says it's only the tension ($mrw^2 + mg$) that causes the elongation. I am at a deadend. Help!

Comment: Is the wire ideal, or non-ideal?

Comment: I have no idea about these two. It's a high school textbook question (NCERT). So, I guess, there not need be much in-depth analysis on the properties of the wire. It's a normal metallic wire

Comment: @Swami : In textbooks of other countries, they often demand a practical and realistic approach to many of the problems. It is unfortunate that NCERT books in our country have come to be known for their inability to promote in-depth understanding of the subject.

Comment: Very true, often some explanations violate some of the basic laws of physics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

Hope this helps! The force of tension actually acts throughout the length of the wire from left to right keeping it together. It 'effectively' acts however, at the center of mass

Comment: I have tried to interpret the existence of all these forces in the following manner, correct me if it sounds stupid:
"Earth pulls the mass with a force equal to 'mg' downwards. The mass in turn pulls the wire downwards with some force, as a result the wire pulls the mass with an equal force of tension upwards. Thus, in other words, wire gets pulled by the mass with the same force of tension downwards. This is the only force that acts on wire if draw a FBD of the wire. However, this tension is equal to the sum of weight and centripetal force that act on the mass, as given by the FBD of mass."

Comment: Absolutely right Swami ! That 'some' force in the third line is mg itself. But since the mass of the earth is extremely large compared to that of the mass, its acceleration is extremely less; thus, the earth's motion is barely affected by the reaction force. Remember, no question is stupid. If anyone thinks so, they probably don't have the guts to answer it.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, the Tension is what always causes the elongation.Here at the lowest point, forces (under vertical equilibrium),(from wire frame of reference which is non inertial) net upward force equals net downward force T=mg + mrw^2 .  Now if we look from outside the wire(inertial frame) then there is no centrifugal force .Here for the wire to rotate, the net force must be equal to the quantity "mrw^2"(the centripetal force required for rotation), which gives T-mg =mrw^2. But remember, ultimately, it is tension which causes the elongation .

Answer (score 1):

If the wire is ideal, the only force that can cause elongation is the net external force on the wire. i.e: mv^2/r + mg. Also however, the magnitude of net external force mv^2/r + mg  is co-incidentally equal to net tension T just to keep the **net** force equal to **zero**. You say that the centrifugal force is the *only* force that causes elongation. But that would be the case if the metallic wire were to rotate in a horizontal circle where the net force **pulling** the wire would only be the centrifugal force. In your case however, even mg pulls and stretches the wire; thus, it would be added to centrifugal force. Hope it helped!

Comment: Can you please draw a free body diagram of the wire? I am still confused.